# ReactJS running on localhost not showing httpOnly token

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, httponly

Why am I not seeing an HTTPOnly cookie in the Browser (Cookies) which I should have received from the server? I tried the request in Postman but the HttpOnly cookie is present.

> Server is deploed in https://example.vercel.app

> Frontend is running in localhost:3000

**Backend Middlewares**

```
  app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true}));
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.use(express.json());
```

**Backend Function**

```
 const cookieOptions = { httpOnly: true, maxAge: MAX_AGE }
 return res.status(200)
           .cookie('token', token, cookieOptions)
           .json({});
```

This is working properly in Postman, however doing this on localhost react-app isn't working.
here's the example of my Axios instance

**Frontend ReactJS Axios instance**

```
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL,
    timeout: 9000,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
});
```

I literally have no idea what's happening, this is my first time using HttpOnly.

Comment: Can you make the problem clear? cookie is not included in response? cookie isn't saved in cookie storage? or saved cookie isn't sent in requests? these 3 are different problems.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for not clarifying the question. Hopefully my edit is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{withCredintials: true}` config option from the request and just added

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Comment: Result still the same